# Pegar data anterior ao ano 2000 MySql

Tags: mysql

Preciso selecionar todos os funcionários com data de contratação anterior ao ano 2000. Como posso colocar essa condição na cláusula **Where**?

```
SELECT nome_funcionario FROM funcionario WHERE data_contratacao...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eu faria de maneira diferente, utilizando a função [`YEAR()`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_year.asp).

```
SELECT nome_funcionario FROM funcionario WHERE YEAR(data_contratacao) < 2000
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT nome_funcionario FROM funcionario WHERE data_contratacao < '2000-01-01'
```